# How to make a file on a webserver to point to an ip address

Tags: redirect, webserver, ip-address, minecraft, tcp

I want to be able to type in www.mydomain.com/file.extenstion into things like minecraft and other tcp/ip connections and it points to my IP Address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a file that contains an IP address, but you can't "make a file point to an IP address" (not in a way minecraft could use anyways). You have to use subdomains.